# How can be $\frac{1}{4\pi R^2}\int_{S}V_{ext}(R)da= V_{ext}(0)$ physically explained?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

I was working out problem 3.1 (4th edition) of Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths, which asks you for the average potential over a spherical surface due to a charge located inside the sphere (as well as verifying an equation).

I understand that, mathematically, one gets for $V_{av}$:

$$V_{av} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon R}$$

And if there is a bunch of $q$ inside the sphere one gets:

$$V_{av} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{4 \pi \epsilon R}$$

**Griffiths shows that the average potential due to exterior charges is the same as if they were placed at the center.**

I understand the Math to get such a result **but I do not understand this result physically speaking.**

How can be the average potential due to an external (out of the sphere) charge $q$ be equal to the average potential due to a charge $q$ located at the center?

I agree that the potential does not have a physical meaning as such, but my intuition tells me that the **difference** between position a (say its value at the center of the sphere) and b (say its value at the position out of the sphere) should matter. Besides, the potential falls off like $1/r$. Thus I do not see how is it possible (**physically speaking**) that:

$$V_{ext}(R)= V_{ext}(0)$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. You first say "due to a charge located inside the sphere", but then you ask for a charge outside the sphere?

Comment: @FGSUZ The exercise focuses on calculating the charge inside. However, my main question is about the average potential outside the sphere and its centre; *why are they equal (physically speaking)* (See my comment to Michael's answer) Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: If so, could you please write the statement of the problem literally? Describe accurately the configuration that you have, and what you want to calculate. IS the sphere physical or imaginary? I just don't see it clear.

Comment: @FGSUZ Please see page 114 Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths (online version), after the proof he says 'But this is precisely the potential due to the charge at the centre of the sphere!' I am seeking a physical explanation of that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I think you mean that "the average potential due to exterior charges is the same as *the potential* at the center". We're not talking about a different charge configuration, we're talking about some aspect about the potential.

2) $V_{ext}(R)= V_{ext}(0)$ is *not* the equation you're looking for, and is why your intuition is failing you. We're not saying that "the potential at $R$ is the same as the potential at $0$, we're saying that the *average* potential over $R$ is equal to the potential at $0$.
$$\frac{1}{4\pi R^2}\int_{S}V_{ext}(R)da= V_{ext}(0) \tag{1}$$

3) Edits. The term "average" is really what's important here. Taking an example of the $1/r$ potential, the contribution of $V$ is "balanced" around the sphere in such a way that $(1)$ is true. If $r$ is smaller, then $V$ is large, but it contributes to less surface area on the sphere, and similarly, if $r$ is large and $V$ is small, then the contribution is large.

On the other hand, Laplace's equation intuitively tells us that the potential will be "smooth", with no local extrema anywhere. I like to imagine that the potential tried to be as boring as possible, hence the behavior over a surface will reflect the behavior of the inside; the field doesn't "fluctuate". It's not surprising that the average of that behavior tells us something about the value of the field within.

Comment: Yes, I agree let me edit the question. But is there a physical reason for $\frac{1}{4\pi R^2}\int_{S}V_{ext}(R)da= V_{ext}(0)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

> How can be the average potential due to an external (out of the sphere) charge $q$
>   be equal to the average potential due to a charge $q$ located at the center?

It's not.  The average potential over a spherical surface of radius $R$ due to a point charge a distance $z > R$ from the center of the sphere is $$V_\text{ave} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 z}
$$
(see §3.1.4 of Griffiths).  Meanwhile, the average potential over the surface if $z < R$ (i.e., the charge is inside the surface) is
$$
V_\text{ave} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 R}.
$$
These quantities are not the same.

Comment: Note that I am trying to understand physically why the average potential over a spherical surface of radius R due to a single point charge q located outside the sphere is equal to the potential due to q at the center of the sphere. Both yield $\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon z}$